# Difference between return a 'new Resource' or return a 'response()->json' in Laravel APIs

Tags: php, laravel, api, resources

Of course I always preferred to make my controllers as clear as possible and i think is good to give the controller only what should be it's responsibility, but in this case i can't see (yet) big improvements in using

```
return new PostResource( $post );
```

instead of

```
return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $post->toArray()
       ]);
```

Comment: Ok. I just find the proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114310/why-or-when-to-use-laravel-resources-collections

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why or when to use Laravel resources/collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114310/why-or-when-to-use-laravel-resources-collections)

Answer (score 0):

Resources & Collections class named in Laravel as API Resource need for return prepare  data structure and hee can reuse, and `response()->json([])` need for return response in JSON type because response can be and HTML, XML, e.t.c